# Add Complex argument for viewmodel constructor in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

There is bindable Item source of Flexlayout

```
<FlexLayout x:Name="playerscollection" Wrap="Wrap" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" />
```

Items in the viewmodel are defined as

```
public ObservableCollection<PlayerModel> Players { get; set; }
```

FlexLayout datatemplate is a content view
I need to assign a specific viewmodel "PlayerViewModel" as the content view BindingContext

```
    public PlayerViewModel(bool showPicker = true, PlayerModel player = null){}
```

So in FlexLayout,

```
<FlexLayout x:Name="playerscollection" Wrap="Wrap" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Players}">
                                            <views:PlayerView >
                                                <views:PlayerView.BindingContext>
                                                    <viewModels:PlayerViewModel>
                                                        <x:Arguments>
                                                            <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
                                                            <models:PlayerModel/>
                                                        </x:Arguments>
                                                    </viewModels:PlayerViewModel>
                                                </views:PlayerView.BindingContext>
                                            </views:PlayerView>
</FlexLayout>
```

But the error says "Type 'PlayerViewModel' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter"

Comment: have you tried adding an empty constructor to PlayerViewModel.cs?

Comment: Why?
 I need To Pass The list items to be binded for corresponding property in Player View

Comment: You are still using the constructor with the parameters, however, the error does mention that you are not defining a parameterless constructor. The framework itself might be looking for it when it is trying to first build out the UI behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a basic demo to test the code and reproduce the error. The error doesn't affect the project build, it's just an **intellisense** error of the IDE. Please ignore the error and deploy the code, it'll work fine.